Playwright in Python: Using :text-matches() with case-insensitive regex for matching names
I'm trying to search for specific names within the HTML of a website using Playwright in Python. I have a list of lowercase names (names_to_find), and I want to match them against names in the HTML that may contain additional text or different cases (e.g., Jerez de la Frontera).
When I use :has-text() or :text(), I get incorrect matches because some HTML elements contain extra text around the name. I can’t use :text-is() either because it’s case-sensitive. So, I thought :text-matches("regex", "i") would be ideal, but it doesn’t return any results.
Below is a simplified version of my code:
import re
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

names_to_find = ['almería', 'cádiz']

async def fetch_geojson(page, names_to_find):
    results = {}

    while names_to_find:
        for name in names_to_find[:]:
            # Pattern for exact word boundary, case-insensitive
            pattern = rf"\b{re.escape(name)}\b"  
            name_found = page.locator(f'td[data-label="nameunit"]:text-matches("{pattern}", "i")').first

            if await name_found.count() > 0:
                print(f"{name} found!")
                # Example placeholder for data storage
                results[name] = "GeoJSON_data_placeholder"  
                names_to_find.remove(name)
                await page.goto("https://example.com")  # Reset for the next iteration

    return results

async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        geojson_results = await fetch_geojson(page, names_to_find)
        await browser.close()

Problem:
When I run this code, :text-matches() does not return any results, even though I expect it to match the names (case-insensitively and with exact word boundaries).
How can I adjust the code to get correct matches, or is there a better approach to perform case-insensitive regex matching on text in Playwright?
Thank you in advance!

This is a pretty good, clear, question, but you might consider including some example HTML that can demonstrate the problem, just to make it that much easier for someone to try and tweak and figure out a solution.

Do you mean you just want to match the names in a case insensitive way? Like, pattern = rf"(?i)\b{re.escape(name)}\b"?

@JeremyBanks Absolutely, I will take that into consideration next time. I found a way around it, but I am still invested in figuring why the regex didn't work! I cannot post the HTML here, but you can visit the site if you would like to see it: https://api-features.ign.es/collections/administrativeunit/items?offset=0&limit=100
`

@WiktorStribiżew Hey, thank you for your answer! I tried this new pattern pattern = rf"(?i)\b{re.escape(name)}\b" but I get SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression. I believe for Playwright's :text-matches the regex is different, as seen in the example on their documentation: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/other-locators

I see, it uses an ECMAScript regex flavor, it does not support inline flags.

There's probably a much easier way to do this than this, but hard to help without the actual page.

@ggorlen Indeed, there it was haha. I was being stubborn on the function to use and how to solve the issue. I found another way around it using Playwright inner_text() and then modifying it, instead of using :text-matches. Example:
name_unit = await rows.nth(i).locator('td[data-label="nameunit"]').inner_text() name_unit_lower = name_unit.strip().lower()
I posted the answer to the issue, but I am not sure it is visible currently...

That also seems questionable practice, albeit possibly necessary sometimes. But the idea with Playwright is using web-first assertions so you don't need to use nth, count, or any other methods that skip auto waiting.

thank you all for your contributions! I am quite new to all of this, but a way around it was using another Playwright function that allowed to manipulate the HTML string to match the text. So, instead of using :text-matches I used inner_text()
Please find the code snippet that was modified below:
while names_to_find:
    # Get all <tr> elements in the table body
    rows = page.locator("table tbody tr")

    # Iterate over each row in the table
    for i in range(await rows.count()):
        # Get the name in lowercase
        name_unit = await rows.nth(i).locator('td[data-label="nameunit"]').inner_text()
        name_unit_lower = name_unit.strip().lower()

